# error on login: SES_UNHANDLED_REJECTION: TypeError: relays[url] is undefined

Tags: bitcoin, lightning-network, nostr, primate

```
SES_UNHANDLED_REJECTION: TypeError: relays[url] is undefined
```

```
        console.log('nostr login');

        const nip07signer = new NDKNip07Signer();
        const ndk = new NDK({
            signer: nip07signer,
            explicitRelayUrls: ['wss://relay.damus.io', 'wss://relay.nostr.band']
        });

        await ndk.connect();

    const user = await nip07signer.user();
    console.log('user:', user);
        const user2 = ndk.getUser({
            npub: user.npub,
        });
    console.log('user2:', user2);
        const profile = await user.fetchProfile();
    console.log('profile:',profile);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a bug in production, its now fixed in latest release of ndk.